# Marble rolling further the more marbles rolled at it

Tags: momentum

Recently, our science teacher had us do an experiment at school, which was a form of Newton’s Cradle. Marbles were placed on a chain of rulers with grooves and a number of marbles were rolled at the the stationary marbles at a 15° angle, determined by placing the first ruler on a book at the halfway point. The surface in the experiment was clean tile. The question was, that does the number of marbles rolled at the stationary marbles affect the distance the last marble rolls.

Obviously, if transfer of momentum is even, no matter the number of marbles rolled at some stationary marbles, the distance the last marble travels will be the same.

Executing the experiment proved my hypothesis to be incorrect. When 1 marble is rolled into 6, the average distance of three trials in ~129.5 cm. When 2 are rolled into 5, the avg. of three trials is ~137.7 cm. Similarly, when 3 are rolled into 4, the avg. of three trials is ~139.5 cm. It seems that the greater the marbles rolled at stationary marbles, the greater the distance the last marble travels. Why is this the case? Perhaps I have made a misconception?

Comment: Descriptive image might go a longer way in helping us understand better what really going on, coz I don't.

Comment: @TechDroid I’ll add.